# Can't specify img to replace in media queries

Tags: html, css, image, media-queries

I can't specify img in this template I used for my client.
I want to put different images on mobile and desktop versions
in the background and the inline css does not let me specify 
the image for some reason I do not know.

**This is the html code:**

```
<aside id="colorlib-hero">
        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li style="background-image: url(images/img_bg_3.jpg);">
                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-md-offset-2 slider-text">
                                <div class="slider-text-inner text-center">
                                    <h2 class=text-bg><span class="mofo">Arbeiten</span></h2>
                                    <h1 class=text-bg><span class="mofo">TRÄUME MIT UNS</span></h1>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
             </ul>
         </div>
     </aside>
```

This is the CSS code I would use for replacing the image:

```
@media (min-width: 601px) {
   #somediv{
       background: url('images/bg.jpg') repeat-x;
   }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
   #somediv{
      background: url('images/bg-mobile.jpg') repeat-x;
   }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: is images/bg-mobile..jpg double dots a typo?

Comment: and a missing } in the end

Comment: It's a typo but don't worry about that, the point is to specify the image in css I don't know which class or id  to specify

Comment: This style may be overwritten with another one from another file. To get a truth you could use developer tools by pressing Ctrl+Shift+i in Chrome and to inspect which stylesheet affected the element finally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `!important;` to override inline style. Example:

```
background: url('images/bg.jpg') repeat-x!important;
```

Although `!important` should be used rarely, more information here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception

Comment: Ok so I found the path (#colorlib-hero > div > ul.slides > li) with google chrome dev tool and I added the !important; now it just doesnt load the background image at any width...I think we are getting somewhere but still does't work

Comment: Where did you set it? On media queries or in your html?

Comment: On media queries, I didn't change anything in html

Comment: @ media (min-width: 601px) {
    #colorlib-hero > div > ul.slides > li{
       background: url("images/bg.jpg") repeat-x !important;
   }
}
@ media (max-width: 600px) {
  #colorlib-hero > div > ul.slides > li{
      background: url("images/bg-mobile.jpg") repeat-x !important;}}

Comment: First of all you have a space between @ and media it should be @media. It works for me. By the way do you really need the inline style? It has no effect if you use media query min-width: 601px.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with your file paths. Test some images from google, just copy image url to see if it works. For me it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `!important` to flag the rule as a more important rule, which overrules all others. Such as:

```
background: url('images/bg.jpg') repeat-x !important;
```

---

Alternatively, if you wanted to use `<img>`, then you could make use of the `<picture>` element as explained [by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture).

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="images/bg.jpg" media="(min-width: 601px)">
    <source srcset="images/bg-mobile.jpg" media="(max-width: 600px)">
    <img src="images/img_bg_3.jpg">
</picture>
```